# Retrieving Branches from GIT url using java code

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, jgit

Currently I'm working on Jgit API to create a branch from source code. I have created the branch successfully and when I create branch I need to validate the branch name shouldn't exists in the current GIT repositary(Online URL : Ex.https://github.com/varunkumar-s/test.git).

Here I want to do list out the branch names from the above url rather from the local git repository. So how can i do this?? I want to have a output of list of branches when I'm giving with the git repository.

Comment: Comment because I haven't used this API. But using the git CLI, I would likely start with [git ls-remote](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) so the [LsRemoteCommand](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/latest/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LsRemoteCommand.html) might be a place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) has a Snippet for this at [ListRemoteRepository](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ListRemoteRepository.java), basically all you need is:

```
    Collection<Ref> refs = Git.lsRemoteRepository()
            .setHeads(true)
            .setRemote(REMOTE_URL)
            .call();

    for (Ref ref : refs) {
        System.out.println("Ref: " + ref);
    }
```

From the ref you can use ref.getName() to get the name which will be something like "refs/heads/".

Comment: This looks great. But I was getting compilation error states that **The method lsRemoteRepository() is undefined for the type Git**. I guess that I am using Jgit JAR version mistakenly. Could you please let me know which version has lsRemoteRepositary method to use. I am currently using the JAR for api.git v3.0.0

Comment: jgit-cookbook is currently using 3.3.2, see https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/pom.xml for details, but it should be available in earlier versions, at least since 2.0.0, so you might need to take a look at how you add the JGit Jar.

Comment: more user-friendly output:

```String branchName = ref.getName().substring(ref.getName().lastIndexOf("/") + 1, ref.getName().length());
System.out.println("Branch: " + branchName + " (" + ref.getObjectId().getName() + ")");
```